# set.erase() is not working for me, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++

Here's my current code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    string numOne, numTwo, numThree;
    int pointOne, pointTwo, pointThree, totalPoint;
    
    set<string> ansOne = { "TOE", "TONGUE", "TOOTH" };
    
    cout << "Give A Body Part That Starts With The Letter T";
    cout << "\n1. ";
    cin >> numOne;

    if (ansOne.find(numOne) == ansOne.end())
    {
        ansOne.erase(numOne);
        cout << "Wrong!";
        pointOne = 0 + 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Nice, You got a Point!";
        pointOne = 1 + 0;
    }
    
    cout << "\n2. ";
    cin >> numTwo;

    if (ansOne.find(numTwo) == ansOne.end())
    {
        ansOne.erase(numTwo);
        cout << "Wrong!";
        pointTwo = 0 + pointOne;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Nice, You got a Point!";
        pointTwo = 1 + pointOne;
    }
    
    cout << "\n3. ";
    cin >> numThree;

    if (ansOne.find(numThree) == ansOne.end())
    {
        ansOne.erase(numThree);
        cout << "Wrong!";
        pointThree = 0 + pointTwo;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Nice, You got a Point!";
        pointThree = 1 + pointTwo;
    }
    
    totalPoint = pointOne + pointTwo + pointThree;
    cout << "\n" << totalPoint;    
}
```

What I want to do is, if the answer is after they put the answers, and if the word is in there, I want to erase that word from the set so they can't duplicate the answer. But it's not getting erased from the set.

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger. You may notice that the `.erase()` never executes after a correct guess. Find out why.

Comment: i just ran it on a debugger and no problems were found, is it the debugger problem?

Comment: oh i saw the problem, i was trying to erase the answer if its wrong, i should put the ansOne.erase into the else part not in if, lol.

Comment: `ansOne.find(numTwo) != ansOne.end()` ? I hope you are trying to erase when you got the answer as input.

Answer (score 0):

Per your declared logic, you put the `erase` in the wrong branch of the `if`, only erasing a word when the word *wasn't* in the `set` already, and *not* erasing it when it was. The first `if`/`else` block would be fixed with:

```
if (ansOne.find(numOne) == ansOne.end())
{
    // Removed ansOne.erase(numOne); here, because you just confirmed it's not in ansOne
    cout << "Wrong!";
    pointOne = 0;
}
else
{
    ansOne.erase(numOne);  // It's in ansOne, remove it so it can't be guessed again
    cout << "Nice, You got a Point!";
    pointOne = 1;
}
```

Similar changes would be made to the other two `if`/`else` blocks.

Note that this code would be *much* simpler with a `for` loop that runs three times and maintains the running total, rather than individual variables for each of three nearly identical tests. For example, the fixed version of your code could simplify to:

```
int main()
{    
    string userinput;    // Just one string for input
    int totalPoints = 0; // Just one score counter
    
    set<string> ansOne = { "TOE", "TONGUE", "TOOTH" };

    cout << "Give A Body Part That Starts With The Letter T";    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        cout << '\n' << i << ". ";  // Number prompts dynamically
        cin >> userinput;

        const auto inputloc = ansOne.find(userinput);  // Storing off iterator speeds erasure later (admittedly not meaningful for three element set
        if (inputloc == ansOne.end())
        {
            cout << "Wrong!";
        }
        else
        {
            ansOne.erase(inputloc);  // Erase with iterator to element found
            cout << "Nice, You got a Point!";
            ++totalPoints;
        }
    }    
    cout << '\n' << totalPoint << '\n';
}
```